# Agnostic query learning for DFAs

Tags: automata-theory, machine-learning, lg.learning, query-complexity

Angluin's membership+equivalence query algorithm allows to efficiently and *exactly* learn a target $n$-state DFA. But what if the target DFA is huge, or the target concept is not even a regular language -- can we still learn a small DFA that approximates the target concept well?

Here's the formal setting. We have a target concept $f^\star$ and distribution $D$ over $\Sigma^*$. A membership query $MQ:\Sigma^*\to\{0,1\}$ returns the value of $f^\star(x)$. An "accuracy query" $AQ$ takes a DFA $f$ as input and returns
$$\mathrm{err}(f):=\sum_{x\in\Sigma^*}D(x)\boldsymbol{1}[f(x)\neq f^\star(x)]$$ a output.

The goal is to efficiently produce a small (up to $n$-states) DFA $f$ with small (or minimum) $\mathrm{err}(f)$ using the oracles $MQ$ and $AQ$. [A trivial solution is to brute-force search over all $n$-state DFAs.]

Have similar problems been considered in the literature? Pointers much appreciated. What is the status of the learning problem I posed?

Edit: It was pointed out off-line that for parity-type concepts, $\mathrm{err}(f)$ might be close to $1/2$. So to clarify:
the question seeks not a bound on the worst-case $\mathrm{err}(f)$,
but rather an efficient procedure of attaining it via an $n$-state DFA.

Comment: So, if you allow an extra slack of say $\\varepsilon$ (and high probability of success only, instead of probability one), you can always cheaply estimate $\mathrm{err}(f)$ by sampling, and this becomes equivalent to proper PAC-learning DFAs with membership queries, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, exactly right. I haven't yet figured out if this question and answer have any relevance https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/153/computational-query-complexity-of-sq-learning?rq=1

Comment: For the agnostic case, where $f^\ast$ may not itself be a DFA, this looks relevant (if I parse the abstract correctly: MQ are not very useful): http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume10/feldman09a/feldman09a.pdf

Comment: Hmm, you may be right. If you turn this into a full answer, I'll accept.

Comment: That still leaves the non-agnostic case open, though (not sure how much of your original motivation that is).

Comment: What do you mean by non-agnostic? Where $f^\star$ is an $n$-state DFA?

Comment: Yes -- or even say an $O(n)$-state one (I am not sure what the above result implies in that case).

Comment: Right... but that's not the case I'm so interested in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if you allow some extra additive slack of $\varepsilon\in(0,1]$ (an input parameter) in the error guarantee, and relax the success probability from one to $1-\delta$ (another input parameter), then the question becomes equivalent to agnostic PAC-learning the class $\mathcal{C}_n$ of $n$-state DFAs with membership queries.

Indeed, while you do not have accuracy queries $\mathrm{AQ}$, those can be easily simulated by sampling in the PAC setting (leading to the $\pm\varepsilon$ and $1-\delta$ relaxation).

However, [this paper by Vitaly Feldman](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v10/feldman09a.html) [Feldman09] shows that then, one may as well forget about the membership queries and focus on honest-to-goodness agnostic PAC learning:

> [...] we give a simple proof that any concept class learnable agnostically by a distribution-independent algorithm with access to membership queries is also learnable agnostically without membership queries.

In this light, provided you are willing to proceed with the error slack and high-probability guarantee, then your question boils down to agnostic PAC learning of $n$-state DFAs.

---

[Feldman09] Vitaly Feldman. *On The Power of Membership Queries in Agnostic Learning.* Journal of Machine Learning Research (JMLR) 10(Feb):163--182, 2009.